# UEFA Champions League fixture with the most goals ever

Tags: football, records, international-sports, champions-league

Tonight, too many goals were scored. In four games six or more goals were scored. 21 goals had been scored only in the first half of just 8 games. And there are another 8 games tomorrow.

In every Champions League fixture the games are always played in two days.
I am wondering if there is a group stage fixture with more than 40 goals in a single night? If no, which is the second one in the list? And which are the best-ever scoring group stage fixtures for both nights?

Comment: Would you like qualifying, or can we start at group stages?

Comment: Didn't the Champs league in its earlier years 1) have 2 group stages (great disparities with team strengths) 2) play all games in one night. (each of the 3 European tournaments (C.L., UEFA cup, CWC cup) were played on different nights)

Answer (score 3):

There is a group stage fixture with 44 goals scored in a single night. It happened on 1st October 1997, but with one major difference: There were 12 matches played in one night.

Both nights record is 63 on 12 & 13th September 2000. Eight matches per night were played then.